# Using Dropbox Folder as Desktop

Tags: desktop, dropbox

I would like to use my Dropbox folder as my Desktop. I know [how to do it in Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17752/use-any-folder-for-your-ubuntu-desktop-even-a-dropbox-folder/) and 
[Windows](http://suefrantz.com/2012/03/13/move-desktop-to-dropbox/), but couldn't find any guide for Mac. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not actually done this it should be possible to redirect your desktop folder to a different location. Since the Dropbox folder is just a folder in your user profile (that the Dropbox app then knows what to do with).

I would avoid using the dropbox folder itself as the desktop folder just to avoid any difficulties or conflicts between macOS and the Dropbox app. Rather I would put a folder called "Desktop" in the Dropbox folder and create a symlink in place of your ~/[username]/Desktop folder that points to ~/[username]/Dropbox/Desktop.

If you are not familiar with symlinks (the Unix version of an Alias but works with system processes) [this link from GigaOm](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/) should be helpful.

The only question that remains is will macOS *allow* you to do this as the default folder structure in your user folder may be protected by the recently introduced "SIP" or System Integrity Protection system.